# Using DKIM private key for nodemailer fails to validate on receiving in inbox

Tags: nodemailer, dkim

I've copied pasted a key from https://www.sparkpost.com/resources/tools/dkim-wizard/

```
    const transport = createTransport({
        host: "mbox.freehostia.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // generated ethereal password
        },
        dkim: {
            domainName: "key1._domainkey.foo.com",
            keySelector: "key1",
            privateKey: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAmLVCBdw9UU6Aw74D0O1bzJ7Bo5vO7J5C/YAgAX1zaOMJF3FC
WjqkRJwzrElPFfqc6p5fgUOn0VOqw/Ao2yAgr9fV72Nl33DkDoejVLbRvPUZyrW/
KHqbeFT875Q/huDnZDaTuVv+CydVPWUnMwrEqO+N45z2UnfDdaQDOoujsvXcGzRf
5Z0hl9fevONs7dEGOUyOujmIlxTZs4DnwVQ30FQWJATCkPGm4wc4Zzoth3MuILNH
.
.
+Q5/b3zm52MnmOTc2Wm3aEs66ZHAMexQb/AUzzEdmNgZ7idinGfdWrU6zh8vmXIL
i+VYyBEexlEpHnB2c7+euIOxd4Ng1BuZZOMo/jwdPhsu04HBA/B0
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`},
    })
```

and added the public key to my domain txt record
however, my email DKIM is not valid when i receive it in my inbox

any ideas what to do? errors from show original:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@foo.com header.s=default header.b=hUBup2c1;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@key1._domainkey.foo.com header.s=key1 header.b=B1aIhDo8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to change domainName

```
        dkim: {
            domainName: "foo.com", <------
            keySelector: "key1",
```

Comment: Ok lol. How is the DNS entry? should be like 'v=DKIM1;p=...'

Comment: Ok, shoulde be passe DKIM ckecker https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-check/ and also https://dkimcore.org/tools/keycheck.html

Comment: I not see other option without possibility to testing. Nodemailer sould add signature a DKIM signature header to email messages. And google, should verifiy this signature with public key. I investigarate on this side

Comment: the emails appear to work though, not landing in spam. Can I send a test one to you?